# PostgreSql PgAdmin4 Debug

Tags: postgresql, debugging, pgadmin-4

I tried to configure PgAdmin4 to use debug, following the manual, but something did not work, because an error as shown in this screenshot occurs:

[image]

I changed `postgresql.conf` to:

```
shared_preload_libraries = ‘$ libdir / other_libraries / plugin_debugger’
```

How should I install the requested pldbgapi extension on Linux / Ubuntu?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the writing corrections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install an extension in a particular database, as it's requesting here, you need to either use the CREATE EXTENSION command in that database, or use PgAdmin 4's interface to install it.

Command method:
Through whichever tool you wish, where you enter regular SQL commands, connect to the relevant database in question and run:

```
CREATE EXTENSION pldbgapi;
```

Or, in PgAdmin 4, open up the nodes for the database you want to install this extension for, right-click on "Extensions", then select Create > Extension...  Now select pldbgapi from the drop-down list next to "Name" and click "Save".

You will need to repeat this process if you need the extension in additional databases within your cluster.

Disclosure: I am an [EnterpriseDB (EDB)](https://enterprisedb.com/) employee

Comment: In PgAdmin 4, pldbapi does not appear in the list of available extensions. How to install pldbapi?

Comment: If the pldbapi extension isn't listed, it will need to be installed through Synaptic Package Manager or apt-get.  You'll see it listed as postgresql-(version)-pldebugger.

Comment: When trying to mark a breakpoint a new error occurs:  

The debugger plugin is not enabled. Please add the plugin to the shared_preload_libraries setting in the postgresql.conf file and restart the database server for indirect debugging.

Comment: In my postgresql.conf: shared_preload_libraries = '$libdir/other_libraries/plugin_debugger' It is correct?

Comment: Assuming that the path is correct, yes, that would work, although it may be enough without a path, just 'plugin_debugger'.

Comment: I changed postgresql.conf to: shared_preload_libraries = 'plugin_debugger' and it solved. Now it's working.

Comment: Thom Brown, Thanks for helping and sharing your expertise.